# BeautifulSoup help w/ multiple strings from multiple <p> tags, find_all researched,

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need help with a small bs4 function,
my web source is structured as follows:

```
article class=" "
div class=" "
figure id=" "
<p><strong>1.</strong> A string of text </p>
<p><strong>2.</strong> A string of text </p>
<p><strong>3.</strong> A string of text </p>
<p><strong>4.</strong> A string of text </p>
etc..
```

i am trying to extract each each `<p>` string of text, while ignoring the rest of the `<p>` tags throughout the webpage.
As of now i am able to extract specific lines with `find_all()[1]`, but i would like to extract multiple lines at once,
my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import SoupStrainer
import requests

def getFact(str):
    page = requests.get("https://thoughtcatalog.com/jacob-geers/2016/04/really-funny-random-weird-facts/")    # call webpage
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.find_all('p')[25].text
    print('Fact Selected')

    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(soup))

    with open('out.txt', 'r') as file:
        fact_ = file.read().rstrip('\n')

    print(fact_)

getFact(str)
```

I'm only able to enter 1 integer in `find_all` but is it possible to select multiple and save to a list?
I have searched bs4 docs, google and SO, and am familiar with the generic input but i cant seem to find anything that relates to `find_all [int options]`

Comment: `find_all` returns an array, so you should iterate the array. Look at [bs docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) the part `One common task is extracting all the URLs found within a page’s <a> tags:` for an example

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by first selecting the `<article>` with class name as `tc_article tc_article-width` and then find all the `<p>` tags using the `.find_all()` method.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import SoupStrainer
import requests

def getFact():
    page = requests.get("https://thoughtcatalog.com/jacob-geers/2016/04/really-funny-random-weird-facts/")    # call webpage
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    ps = soup.find('article', class_='tc_article tc_article-width').find_all('p')
    print('Facts:')
    for i in ps:
        print(i.text.strip())

getFact()
```

```
Facts:
1. Most toilets flush in E flat.
2. A raisin dropped in a glass of fresh champagne will bounce up and down continuously from the bottom of the glass to the top.
3. Cap’n Crunch’s full name is Horatio Magellan Crunch.
4. The Vatican City is the country that drinks the most wine per capita at 74 liters per citizen per year.
5. Approximately 40,000 Americans are injured by toilets each year.
.
.
.
25. The US Treasury once considered producing doughnut-shaped coins!
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i started trying a similar approach after i asked the question, but could not figure it out for the life of me. thanks again